# How to validate a year I enter in textbox using jquery rule?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox in HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="register-form" novalidate>
  Session:
  <input type="text" name="session" id="session"/>
  <input type='submit' name='add' value='Save'/>
</form>
```

I want the date I enter in textbox to be between 2000 & 2014 and input like 212, 998 etc. should be rejected. How to validate it in JQuery?

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#register-form").validate({
      rules: {      
        session: {
          required: true,
        },  
      },
      messages: {
        session: "Please enter year",                       
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
      }
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use range to specify the range.

$("#register-form").validate({

```
    rules: {        
        session: {
            required: true,
            range:[2000,2014]

        },  

 },

    messages: {
    session: "Please enter year",                       
    },


    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the "min" & "max" methods of the jQuery plugin like that:

```
$("#register-form").validate({
    rules: {        
        session: {
            required: true,
            min: 2000,
            max: 2014     
        },  
 },
    messages: {
    session: "Please enter year",                       
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Sources: 
http://jqueryvalidation.org/min-method
http://jqueryvalidation.org/max-method/

Answer (score 2):

You can custom validation rule like this

```
$.validator.addMethod("validYear", function(value, element) {
    return ((parseInt(value) > 1999) && parseInt(value) < 2015);
}, "Year should  be between 2000-2014");
```

And then use this to define the rule

```
$("#register-form").validate({
    rules: {        
        session: {
            required: true,
            validYear:true
        },  
 },
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3bg9/1)**