# How to validate input date html year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, date

I want the date input to stop typing once the year has 4 digits. I tried using the min and max component from HTML, but it stills allows you to type erasing the first digit. See example 1.

See example 2 to see that year can be typed with more than 4 digits.

Here are my two test runs, I also tried creating a method with JS using the "onchange" component from HTML and I tried, but none of this seems to work...

https://fiddle.jshell.net/jaelsvd/98xww3qg/9/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Example 1</label>
 <input id="date1" type="date" min="1990-12-31" max="2050-12-30">
  <br />
   <label>Example 2</label>
  <input id="date2" type="date" />
```

Comment: Try again with the `onkeypress` JavaScript event. The `onchange` event does not fire while you type inside the input.

Comment: @GramThanos—what about input that doesn't cause a keypress event to be dispatched (like pasting using a mouse)?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*How to validate a year I enter in textbox using jquery rule?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809035/how-to-validate-a-year-i-enter-in-textbox-using-jquery-rule)

Comment: @RobG Yeah, this is a problem too. So... someone can use all the event :P

Comment: The problem with the onkeypress is that it's not detecting the value of my year correctly. Maybe cause it triggers the method before even detecting the actual value of the date. :P I wish it just worked as easy as maxlenght=8, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more flexibility, you can use textbox input and check on keypress event, and decide to accept or reject the pressed key like below:

```
<input type="text" id="my_date" placeholder="MM/dd/YYYY" />

<script>
    var myDate = document.querySelector('#my_date');
    myDate.onkeypress = function (evt) {
        var _evt = evt || windows.event;
        var keyCode = _evt.keyCode || _evt.charCode;
        var sKey = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
        // TODO: test for key value

        // Test for text lenth
        var text = this.value;
        // TODO: test value, return true to accept, false to reject.
        if (text.length > 10) {
            alert(text + ' length reach quota.');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What about values that are input without using the keyboard (i.e. don't cause a keyboard event to be dispatched)?

Comment: I'm thinking I'll use something like this, but instead of the alert I'll use a onpresskey disabled. "False"

Comment: @RobG: to handle copy & paste, maybe to catch 'onchange' and check for value and reject the whole text.

Comment: @JaelSaavedra, if this help, please accept the answer.

Comment: @KhoaBui it's not working, I tried changing the input type to date and also trying to get rid of the last 0(extra character), if I try the condition text.length > 9 it doesn't work either, heres an example, I still need to delete the extra digit. https://jsfiddle.net/jaelsvd/8p35t1ep/1/

Comment: @JaelSaavedra I don't give the exact working code for you question, but give an approach so that you can learn and adjust according to your specific need. Notice the TODO in my sample code.

Comment: @JaelSaavedra As developer, we need hint or idea to try, not exact code that run at first copy & paste.

Answer (score 1):

Set `maxlength` and use `pattern` along with `required` if you want html5 built in validation:

```html
<form>
  <label for ="date2">Example 2</label>
  <input id="date2" type="date" pattern="\d{4}" maxlength="4"  required />
  <button>
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, can use :
(1) FormValidation ([this link](http://formvalidation.io)), (2) DateRangePicker - Jquery ([this link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/))

Comment: This isn't an answer, it might be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the component "date" sets 000's when pressing a key. I had to change the condition and read the 000 before and then set the condition. This worked.

```js
var myDate = document.querySelector('#my_date');
    myDate.onkeypress = function (evt) {
        var _evt = evt || windows.event;
        var keyCode = _evt.keyCode || _evt.charCode;
        var sKey = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
        
        var text = this.value;
         var res = text.substring(0, 3);
         var res2 = text.substring(0,2);
         var res3  = text.substring(0,1);
         if(res === "000" || res2 === "00" || res3 ==="0"){
             return true;
         }else{
            if (text.length >= 9) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
         }
        
    };
```

```html
<input type="date" id="my_date" placeholder="MM/dd/YYYY" />
```